# Multi-row INSERT vs. repeatedly calling PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

If I have a table created with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE names (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR);
```

And a `List<String> names` of names I want to add to the table, I see two ways of going about this.

The simple, brute force solution is to manually construct the SQL, like so:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES ("+
             Joiner.on("), (").join(names)+
             ");";
conn.createStatement().execute(sql);
```

This hits the DB exactly once, and seems intuitive and straightforward.  I'm aware there are SQL-Injection concerns, but for the sake of the question let's assume those are addressed already.

The alternative would be to use a prepared statement, and the [JDBC docs suggest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) executing that statement repeatedly, like so:

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement addNames = con.prepareStatement(
   "INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES (?);");

for (String name : names) {
    addNames.setString(1, name);
    addNames.executeUpdate();
    con.commit();
}
con.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Is it really the case that executing a `PreparedStatement` repeatedly like this is more desirable than simply constructing the query String and executing it directly?

Comment: The problem with many performance related questions is that they are *desperately theoretical*.   
One have no table, no data to insert, not a single query to run, no bottleneck to deal with, but for some reason bugs himself with a question out of nowhere - which is faster.

Comment: For a more fair comparison, you should 1) move the `con.commit()` out of the loop and 2) use batched updates (though it depends on the driver and database if that has a different performance)

Comment: The example in the JDBC docs has `con.commit();` in the loop, so that's why I did that.  Was similarly somewhat skeptical of having the commit in the loop.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I disagree - issuing `O(n)` requests against a database is not "needlessly theoretical", it's a critically important concern for a scalable application.  It seems to me the best security practice (use PreparedStatement) flies in the face of the best scalability practice (minimize DB calls) and I'm trying to understand where the appropriate balance is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two more options:

- Use `PreparedStatement.addBatch()`. For many databases, this will reduce the number of server round trips. Not for all databases however (for example, not for the H2 database).
- Use `PreparedStatement`, but with multiple rows, in batches:

  ```
  INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES (?), (?), (?), (?), (?), (?), (?), (?);
  ```

The second should reduce server roundtrips for all databases, but it is a bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I missed or misunderstood `addBatch()`/`executeBatch`, doing more digging this makes perfect sense, and is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**yes its faster**
its Because each time a java application sends a new SQL statement to the Database,the server checks for syntax errors,prepares a plan for executing the statement and executes it.

If the same statement is sent again,though the DB server checks to see whether it has already recieved one exactly like it. If so the server does not check its syntax and prepare an execution plan for it so the server just executes it.

To take advantage of this database feature,java provides for the use of prepared statement .This feature lets you send send statements to the database server that gets executed repeatedly by accepting the parameter values that are sent to it.That improves the database performance because the database server only has to check the syntax and prepare the execution plan once for each statement.

Comment: I'd imagine the bigger bottleneck would be the back-and-forth between the server and the client, not the validation time.  From your description, both statements get validated once, so the fact that `PreparedStatement` doesn't need to be validated more than once doesn't really seem helpful, seeing as the naive solution only has one query to run in the first place...